# Publish an update to a flutter app from android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have a fully built android app in Flutter, but Flutter is getting stopped in my workplace so we have to redesign the whole app in Android Studio, and XCode respectively...

The Flutter version is already in google play. So, if we make a new Android App in Android Studio can I just push the update to Google Play, or do we need something else?

And how we can do those steps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may continue using the app name published on Play Store and App Store as long as your applicationId (in Android) and bundleId (iOS) are configured the same as in your existing flutter project.

For Android, make sure the signing key configuration is same as the existing one.